# SQL Server get Max record

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following

```
(SELECT 
    ts.PID, 
    tt.ID, 
    tt.ItemOrder,
    tt.DisplayVal as Task, 
    tt.Responsible as  ResParty, 
    tt.DaysDue, 
    DATEADD(day, tt.DaysDue, PgStartDate) as DueDate,
    ts.spate As ActualDate , 
    ps.PgStartDate as ProgramDate
FROM tblTimeline tt 
CROSS JOIN tblSers ts
JOIN PG ps ON ps.PID = ts.PId
WHERE tt.ID = 2 
AND ps.cancelled = 0 ) 

t1
INNER JOIN(

SELECT 
    ts.PID,  
    max(DATEADD(day, tt.DaysDue, PgStartDate)) as DueDate 
FROM tblTimeline tt 
CROSS JOIN tblSers ts
JOIN PG ps on ps.PID = ts.PId
WHERE tt.ID = 2 
AND ps.cancelled = 0) 

t2
  ON t1.PID = t2.PID 
  AND t1.DueDate = t2.DueDate
```

In `t1`, what I have is duplicates for `PID, DueDate` for a given row.

I like to get the full rows for each `PID`, I like to show the row that has the Max `DueDate`.

I get incorrect syntax near t1, t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing a `GROUP BY` as well as the start of your initial `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *  --missing this
FROM      --missing this
(
  select ts.PID, 
     tt.ID, 
     tt.ItemOrder,
     tt.DisplayVal as Task,
     tt.Responsible as  ResParty, 
     tt.DaysDue, 
     DATEADD(day, tt.DaysDue, PgStartDate) as DueDate,
     ts.spate As ActualDate , 
     ps.PgStartDate as ProgramDate
  from tblTimeline tt 
  cross join tblSers ts
  join PG ps on ps.PID = ts.PId
  where tt.ID = 2 and ps.cancelled = 0 
) t1
inner join 
(
  select ts.PID,  
    max(DATEADD(day, tt.DaysDue, PgStartDate)) as DueDate 
  from tblTimeline tt cross join tblSers ts
  join PG ps 
    on ps.PID = ts.PId
  where tt.ID = 2 and ps.cancelled = 0 
  GROUP BY ts.PID   --missing this
) t2
  on t1.PID = t2.PID 
  and t1.DueDate = t2.DueDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Group By.

```
select ts.PID,  max(DATEADD(day, tt.DaysDue, PgStartDate)) as DueDate 
   from tblTimeline tt cross join tblSers ts
   join PG ps on ps.PID = ts.PId
   where tt.ID = 2 and ps.cancelled = 0
   group by ts.PID
```

Comment: Thanks , I entered this but still does not recognize t1, t2. Am I doing something wrong here